# product of Permutation in $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

Consider the permutations $\alpha, \beta, \beta'$ in $S_n$ and say $\beta$ is conjugate to $\beta'$, i.e. $\beta' = \alpha\circ\beta\circ\alpha^{-1}$. I'm having problems understanding what the product of the permutations, say 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 ... & n \\
\beta(1) & \beta(2) ... &\beta(n) \\
\end{pmatrix}
\circ
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 ... & n \\
\alpha^{-1}(1) & \alpha^{-1}(2) ... &\alpha^{-1}(n) \\
\end{pmatrix} 
$$
in the matrix notation looks like. How do I proceed in finding the product. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If $\beta$ takes $x$ to $y$ then $\alpha\beta\alpha^{-1}$ takes $\alpha(x)$ to $\alpha(y)$, since $$\alpha\beta\alpha^{-1}(\alpha(x))=\alpha(\beta(x))=\alpha(y)$$

Comment: That is the most succint description of the situation I've ever read.